# Using Seaborn: lmplot's

Tags: python, python-3.x, seaborn, lmplot

I am trying to create a lmplot using these variables

The code is supposed to create subplots based of the manuf column

This is my current code and the error I am getting:

```
sns.lmplot(x="Carbo", y="Sugars", col='Manuf',data=cereals_data3)

TypeError: Cannot cast array data from dtype('int64') to dtype('int32') according to the rule 'safe'
```

Any advice on how to fix this would be greatly appreciated, thanks!!

Here are the first 10 rows just to show the data I am working with

[image]

In response to a comment:
[image]
[image]